# flutter-webview can't appear floatingactionbutton in certain webpage

Tags: flutter, url, floating-action-button

I'm a beginner at Flutter language, and recently I used Flutter WebView to load HTTP pages.I am also trying to only display the actionfloatingbutton on the login page, and it has been confirmed that the URL of the login page can be blocked with JavaScript, but the floatingactionbutton cannot be displayed, is there any problem with this? My webview_flutter version: 2.0.0

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('WebView Test'),
      ),
      body: WebView(
        initialUrl: currentUrl,
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
          _controller = webViewController;
        },
        onPageFinished: (url) {
          debugPrint('URL: $url');
          _getCurrentUrl();
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: _fingerPrinter(),
    );
  }

  void _getCurrentUrl() async {
    if (_controller != null) {
      String? url =  await _controller!.evaluateJavascript("window.location.href");
      if (url != null && url != currentUrl) {
        setState(() {
          currentUrl = url;
        });
        debugPrint('Current URL: $currentUrl');
        // You can handle your logic here related to the intercepted URL
      }
    }
  }

  Widget _fingerPrinter() {
    if (currentUrl == "xxxxxxxxx/sign-in") {
      // Show the floating action button only on the login page
      return FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          final authenticate = await LocalAuth.authenticate();
          setState(() {
            authenticated = authenticate;
          });
          const snackBar = SnackBar(
            content: Text('You are authenticated.'),
          );
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.fingerprint),
      );
    }
    return Container();
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkce5.png)

Comment: Do you really have `"xxxxxxxxx/sign-in"` there or the actual url? And maybe add some prints inside `_fingerPrinter` just to see if it comes in the if and if it doesn't you'll know the if check is wrong

Comment: I can confirm that the URL is accessible, but I hide it. Thank you for the suggestion, it is indeed a problem that the if check in the _fingerprinter cannot pass. Is there a problem with string comparison?

Comment: There shouldn't be. Must be really a difference between currentUrl and the string you compare it with. Maybe one includes the https:// part and the other not? Or an uppercase lowercase difference?

Comment: Uh-huh I didn't notice that the  return string contains "", now my button can be displayed smoothly, thank you very much.